# When trying to upload file, axios throw "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: express, axios, vuejs3, multer

I'm using VueJs3, Multer middleware for file uploading, expressJs. Its pretty new for me, so probably it is just a small mistake and i couldn't find it... After submit in console axios throw this error : "Request failed with status code 404".

And `console.log(formData.append("file", this.file))` gives 'undefined'.

Some code from component:

```js
import axios from "axios"
export default {
    name: "FileUpload",
    data() {
        return {
            file: "",
            message: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSelect() {
            const file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
            this.file = file
        },
        async onSubmit() {
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("file", this.file)
            try {
                await axios.post("/upload", formData)
                this.message = "Upload successfully"
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                this.message = "Something went wrong :("
            }
        },
    },
}
```

And back-end:

```js
const express = require("express")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
// const db = require("./app/config/db.config")
const multer = require("multer")

dotenv.config()

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

const upload = multer({
    dest: "./uploads",
})

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081",
}


app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    res.json({ file: req.file })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

I been trying to look for solutions in some tutorials, but probably mistake is to small for my rookie eyes at the moment...

Comment: it will be great if you convert that image to base64 and then on server side you can handle it

Comment: on server there too many way to proceed with that practice but one of the best practice is try to upload base64 image in request and server will save into the specific path & save that path in your db and on fetching time reserve that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which axios version you are using but you could try switching the versions because some versions handle `multipart/form-data` differently.

from [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#-automatic-serialization-to-formdata)

> Starting from `v0.27.0`, Axios supports automatic object serialization to a FormData object if the request `Content-Type` header is set to `multipart/form-data`.

I take this to mean that the header needs to be defined explicitly

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append("file", this.file)
await axios.post("/upload", formData, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
})
```

you can also try using the `postForm` method

[docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#files-posting)

```js
await axios.postForm("/upload", {file: this.file})
// or with multipart
await axios.postForm("/upload", {'files[]': [this.file]})
```

I would also recommend that you look at the network panel to see if that header is included, and try sending the request directly with something like postman or insomnia to determine definitively whether the issue is on the front-end or back-end.

Comment: Axios version : "axios": "^1.1.3"

Comment: it seems that the header content definition is required for that version, you can also try postForm, which might not need the header set